# Package size differs between dpkg-query and apt-cahce

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt, dpkg

I was trying to get a package size installed on my Ubuntu-VM and so I tried 2 different commands: **dpkg-query** and **apt-cache**. I did that for 2 packages I previously installed: **git** and **terminator**:

**For git package:**

```
1. $ dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | grep git
    Output:
    69  elpa-git-commit
    1446    elpa-magit
    94  elpa-magit-popup
    35680   git
    1233    git-cvs
    864 git-daemon-run
    11263   git-doc
    ...
```

while

```
2. $ apt-cache show git | grep '^Size:'
    Output:
    Size: 4554416
    Size: 4553836
```

**For terminator package:**

```
3. $ dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' | grep terminator
   Output: 2099 terminator
```

while

```
4. $ apt-cache show terminator| grep '^Size:'
   Output: Size: 313088
```

**So I got a little confused. My questions:**

1. Why dpkg-query on "git" gives so many packages (containing the word 'git') while apt-cache on "git" gives ONLY 2 simple results (probably for 2 different versions)
2. Why dpkg-query on "terminator" gives a different size than apt-cache on "terminator" package?

Comment: Simple command : `dpkg -s git | grep Size` ... and the reply is `Installed-Size:  ......`

Answer (score 1):

1. You’re not running `dpkg-query` on `git`, you’re running `dpkg-query` on all packages and filtering the output on `git`. Try

   ```
   dpkg-query -Wf '${Installed-Size}\t${Package}\n' git
   ```

   instead.
2. `apt-cache`’s `Size` field shows the package file’s size, *i.e.* the size of the corresponding `.deb` file, not the package’s installed size. Use `apt show` instead to see both the download size and installed size.